# Can I make a AJAX call back from another page in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

For example, I have a web page called "myApplication.html", and I click the menu, it loads the "menu.html", but it is not loading the whole page, it just like a facebook by clicking the "Account" on the right, it is a part of web site only.

When I click the menu.html items, I don't want the whole page to reload, I only reload some of the content in the myApplication.html, for example, reload a div tag, which id is "photo".

I know that it can put all the code in one html, by not calling menu.html, but I think it is to complex to separate the work. Also suggestions?

myApplication.html -> menu.html -> click on menu.html's menu item -> reload myApplication.html "photo" tag

Comment: can you edit your question for typo and clear up what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I would highly rcommend checking out jquery, which has awesome support for ajax  what you want to do would be as simple as $('div').load('menu.html')

Comment: but I want the menu.html do some call back to myApplication.html, is it possible to do so?

Comment: Yeah, menu.html will get injected into your DOM, and any functions which are declared in the main HTML file will be available to the menu file.